# Password validation (regex?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, validation, passwords

I need to write some validation rules for a user password with the following requirements. C# ASP.NET MVC.

> Passwords must be 6 - 8 characters
>   Must include at least one character
>   each from at least three of the
>   following categories:

1. Upper-case letters
2. Lower-case letters
3. Numeric digits
4. Non-alpha-numeric characters (e.g.,!@#$%...)

> Must not contain any
>   sequence of 3 or more characters in
>   common with the username 
> Must not
>   repeat any of the previous 1 passwords
>   Must be changed if the password is
>   believed to be compromised in any way

Currently i've written a bunch of really messy validation rules using if statements and loops (especially the 3 characters in sequence with username part), which is currently functional but it just feels like its wrong. Is there a better approach I can take?

Thankyou

Comment: Care to share what you previously had? It may be educational to review your regex and make it more suitable.

Comment: "Must not repeat any of the previous 1 passwords" - whatever you do, don't store the old passwords. Store the hashes and salts and only ever compare hashed values.

Comment: I understand the lower bound. But why is there an upper bound?

Comment: I'm always in favour of using a regex where it's appropriate, and it would be good here. But the downside of using a regex for this is that you'll only get a true/false value of whether it matches or not. Most systems these days have gone down the route of a password strength checker, to give the user some feedback as to how close their password is to being strong enough. But for that you'll need to check the criteria individually so you can produce a score. More code than a regex, but in this case possibly worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote one very similar to what you are describing. They can be done as a regular expression, and when complete (at least for myself) it was a very rewarding accomplishment.

To accomplish this you are going to need to use a regex feature called lookaheads. See [the information](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) on the [regular-expression.info](http://regular-expression.info) site for all the gory details.

The second thing you will need is a real time regular expression tester to help you prototype your regex. I suggestion you check out [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/). Create several passwords that should work, and some that shouldn't work and start from there as your starting point.

**Edit:**
To elaborate on my above comment. Not every one of your requirements can or should be solved via a regex. Namely, the requirements you listed as:

> - Must not contain any sequence of 3 or more characters in common with the username
> - Must not repeat any of the previous 1 passwords
> - Must be changed if the password is believed to be compromised in any way

Should probably be handled separately from the main password validation regex, as these are highly contextual. The "*sequence of 3 or more characters in common with the username*" can probably be handled on the client side. However, the other two items are probably best left handled on the server side.