# Password DataAnnotation in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password validation (regex?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116147/password-validation-regex)

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 application and I have applied

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

DataAnnotation to my Password field. I want to make sure that password must be at least 6 characters, no more than 18 characters, and must include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, and one numeric digit. Do I need to add regular expression or DataType.password will do all this ?

Please suggest

Comment: How is this related to entity framework?

Comment: Not related to Entity Framework

Answer (score 37):

You must write exactly what you want.
Write this:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(18, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[RegularExpression(@"^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).+$")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Hadas Could you explain what you have written in the regularExpression data annotation? I am trying to build a password req

Comment: Just:
[RegularExpression("^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)).+$", ErrorMessage = "Error message")]